# GeoServer WMS GetMap request from multiple layers

Tags: geoserver, getmap

I'm trying to form a GetMap request for my geoserver that returns data (.png image) from two layers (buildings and roads).

Request looks like this:

```
https://mysite.net/geoserver/wms?request=GetMap&service=WMS&version=1.1.1&layers=buildings,roads&styles=buildings,roads&srs=EPSG%3A3765&bbox=397034,4909706,397213,4909832&&width=600&height=600&format=image%2Fpng
```

And this is the response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE ServiceExceptionReport SYSTEM 
"https://mysite.net/geoserver/schemas/wms/1.1.1/WMS_exception_1_1_1.dtd">
<ServiceExceptionReport version="1.1.1" >
    <ServiceException code="LayerNotDefined" locator="layers">
      Could not find layer  roads
</ServiceException>
</ServiceExceptionReport>
```

If I want data from only one layer, it works. Like example below (returns image with buildings only):

```
https://mysite.net/geoserver/wms?request=GetMap&service=WMS&version=1.1.1&layers=buildings&styles=buildings&srs=EPSG%3A3765&bbox=397034,4909706,397213,4909832&&width=600&height=600&format=image%2Fpng
```

How can I request an image that contains both layers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to work out why layer `roads` is not found. Possible causes are:

- you spelt the name wrong (including case `Roads` is not the same as `roads`).
- The layer you requested is in a workspace, most GeoServer layers are found in a workspace so you ask for `topp:states` not `states` (unless you are using the WMS endpoint in the `topp` workspace, so the URL includes `topp`).
- You are using a workspace and the layer you are requesting is in another workspace.
- You never got round to creating the layer.

Comment: Both layers are in same workspace, but I had to specify workspace for both layers in this case (while in case of buildings only, it worked without workspace parameter). Thanks! Here's the request that works now: ```https://mysite.net/geoserver/wms?request=GetMap&service=WMS&version=1.1.1&layers=myworkspace:buildings,myworkspace:roads&styles=buildings,roads&srs=EPSG%3A3765&bbox=397034,4909706,397213,4909832&&width=600&height=600&format=image%2Fpng```

Comment: An URL that can be used for testing https://demo.geo-solutions.it/geoserver/wms?REQUEST=GetMap&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&WIDTH=993&HEIGHT=809&LAYERS=topp%3Atasmania_state_boundaries%2Ctopp%3Atasmania_roads&TRANSPARENT=TRUE&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&BBOX=143.65,-43.64,148.65,-39.57&SRS=EPSG:4326&STYLES=